# Error building react app "Path must be a string. Received undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React js. When i run the command to start the application using 
`npm start`
i get the following error in browser

````
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:1236:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/anilu/Public/PROJECTS/salesfon/salesx-react/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem. I assume you are using `react-scripts`. Just update it to `3.4.x`. - It worked for me.

Cheers,
D.